# Trouble importing numba

Tags: python, python-3.3, numba

Ok, I'm using python 3.3. I have numpy, llvm, llvmpy, llpyhton, llvm_array, llvm_cbuilder and llvmath installed. I have also installed numba.

However, when trying to import via `import numba`, the following error appears. I have no idea of what could be missing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/pablo/workspace/Pruebas/src/Prueba2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numba
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from numba import utils, typesystem
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numba/utils.py", line 102, in <module>
    context = get_minivect_context()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numba/utils.py", line 100, in get_minivect_context
    return NumbaContext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numba/minivect/miniast.py", line 138, in __init__
    import llvm.core as llvm_py_not_available # llvm-py not available
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/llvm/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from llvmpy import extra
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/llvmpy/extra.py", line 6, in <module>
    from llvmpy import _api
ImportError: libLLVM-3.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if `libLLVM-3.2.so` exists in your `$PATH`, first place to look would probably be `/usr/lib/`. `LLVM` is currently in version `3.3` so your system might have installed `3.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong.
I added the anaconda folders to the deafault python3 interpreter, instead of installing numba directly in the packages folder.